# Jenkins script quitting prematurely when using npm install on Windows

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, gruntjs

In my Jenkins job I want to build a JavaScript app using Grunt. The Jenkins build scripts creates a build directory (if it doesn't already exist), changes to that directory and runs:

```
npm install grunt
npm install grunt-zip
grunt --gruntfile=[something]
```

(Of course `grunt-cli` is installed globally.) When I build the job, the first statement causes Grunt and dependencies to be pulled down as expected. However, the job then terminates successfully:

```
Archiving artifacts
No emails were triggered.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

The second `npm install` is not run. Any idea why the script is terminating after running `npm install` instead of continuing to the subsequent statements?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use devDependencies in package.json and pull them all in with a single 'npm install'?

Comment: Actually I figured this one out just now. `npm` is implemented as a batch file (using bash shell) so it needs to be called from the Jenkins script using `call`, like so: `call npm install grunt`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

So it turns out that `npm` is a batch file, not an executable, so it needs to be invoked using `call` from the Jenkins script:

```
call npm install grunt
```

Comment: Note that this _only_ applies to Windows.

Comment: this also applies to calling grunt

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend not using the local grunt / nodejs install, but instead getting jenkins to do this for you!

it's much easier and means there's less coupling to system specific installs and variables.

steps:

a) use nodejs jenkins plugin + get it to install nodejs on machine/grunt-cli -> [Jenkins integration with Grunt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765428/jenkins-integration-with-grunt/22014724#22014724)

b) populate your package.json with any nodejs dependances required, eg grunt/grunt-zip etc

c) when running grunt just do a "npm update" before "grunt" command

that way your not doing explicit npm install, it's all configured from your package.json, and your build scripts will be less brittle, and your developers can use the same steps as the build server, eg "npm update;grunt" locally same as build server

Answer (score 0):

For future googlers:

use command chaining for this.

This works:
npm install && npm install install grunt-zip

This wont work:
npm install 
npm install grunt-zip